# Is this React hook trick has any bad consequences?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is close-to-live example of my code.

```
const Form = (props) => {
  const { onSubmit } = props;
  const [state, setState] = useState({ text: '' });

  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;

    setState((currentState) => {
      return {
        ...currentState,
        [name]: value,
      };
    });
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(() => {
    setState((currentState) => {
      onSubmit(currentState);
      return currentState;
    });
  }, [onSubmit]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input value={state.text} name="text" onChange={handleChange} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

The trick is in the `handleSubmit` function. I use `setState`, but I'm not going to modify this state. It's just allow me to avoid `state` as a dependency of `useCallback` hook. Because of that, my `handleSubmit` function doesn't recreates after every state change.  I already have tested it, it works. In this case submit doesn't call a render, but it looks very tricky for me. Is it okay to do like this?

Comment: whats wrong with re-creating the `handleSubmit` function when state changes? I would prefer knowing the side effects of a function than non standard hard to follow code

Comment: This code has no guaranties that the `setState` callback will be called with the final updated state value since React can batch `setState` calls and yours could be called halfway through the batch. It's mostly going to work, but it's a race-condition waiting to happen, or just unnecessary altogether since both change and submit events are unlikely to trigger at the same time.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `state` as a dependency of `useCallback`? If the callback is using it, just add it as a dependency. Have you noticed and measured a rendering bottleneck with this form callback changing too often?

Comment: @JohnRuddell nothing is wrong, but I think that not to do something is better then do something. Why should I use `useCalback` in this case? If every render I recreate callback function then `useCallback` allmost useless.

Comment: @EmileBergeron sounds improbable, but thanks for the idea. I'll explore that. About your question. IMO, `useCallback` in this case become useless. Only additional checks, becouse if `state` store all form values, it will change almost every render.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna add that after some real life cases I don't recommend use this way. It could be cause of problems when some of your Parent components update their state after the `onSubmit` callback call.